# Strange symbol in output filename from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, rename, filenames, symbols

I have a bash script that take a single text file 'power_coords.txt' containing 115 rows of data, and within each row there are four (space separated) columns containing x,y,z coordinates (first 3 cols) and a name (4th col). Example:

```
36 54 19 cotc1
45 13 -27 cotc2
1 -6 14 cotc3
....
```

My script runs the following lines of code to run an operation on each line of the text file:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="power_coords.txt"  
while IFS=" " read x y z name
do  
fslmaths avg152T1.nii.gz -mul 0 -add 1 -roi $x 1 $y 1 $z 1 0 1 $name -odt float
done < "$input"
```

This appears to work just fine, however when I run the code I get a strange symbol in each filename created:
[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix? Or a simple way to clean up the filenames (i.e., remove the bit that looks like lego) after the script has run?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The small square in your screenshot says "000D", so it's just a [CR newline symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation).

First of all, I would recommend checking what's in the variable `$name`, by just printing it:

```
while IFS=" " read x y z name
do  
  echo "aaa${name}bbb"
done < "$input"
```

`aaa` and `bbb` are there to more easily see the output.

It would also help to check what character is used in `power_coords.txt`. You can check it by passing path to the [utility `file`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file). It should print out which "line terminator" is used in file.

After figuring out what's being read into `$name`, you can either convert line breaks in `power_coords.txt`, or tweak `IFS` to allow CR to be treated as delimiter as well.

Comment: Oh ok - is there a way to suppress that being included when the file is created?

Comment: @thefloatingkudu You can get `read` to trim the CR as whitespace with `while IFS=$' \r' read ...`